# Does adding a SSL Certificate interrupt my webservice connection with my iOS app?

Tags: ios, web-services, ssl

I've got an iOS application running in the app store.
It's a pre Xcode 7/iOS9 build.

The last couple of months our company started growing and we decided to add a SSL Certificate to our domain.
Our app connects to a web-service located at http://login."ourDomain".nl/api/v1/

I'm using AFNetworking library

So my question is: does adding a SSL Certificate interrupt our apps connection with our web-service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you configure your server.

Technically, adding an SSL certificate will only allow you to access your API through `https://login.yourdomain.nl/api/v1/`.

Now good practice would be to close the HTTP endpoint or make it redirect to the HTTPS endpoint in order to make sure that all connections use the now secure connection. But obviously you don't have to make that change and things will continue to work using HTTP connections.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

We do want to update the app to change the link to https but it takes around 10 days for Apple to accept it.

So it technically wouldn't work but if we redirect the http to https it will work?

Comment: The redirection may work, but that really depends on your app. My advice is to just try and see what happens.